# Help me identify the components of my switchgear?

Tags: switch, electrical-panel

I have a basic understanding of what I need to do when the power line goes down, though sometimes different switches pop and would like to understand more of what does what. I have no knowledge in electronic components I'm afraid, can someone help me understand the function of every switch? Is it possible to do from this image?

P.S.: Yes, it is my switchgear. I can provide more images if needed!

[image: Switchgear 1]

Comment: Knowing what this is for (solar, grid, batteries, etc) and what you do when the power goes out would be helpful for a start.

Comment: It's the main power switchgear of the house, it controls the electrical wiring in the condominium. I don't know the difference between batteries and grid, though we don't have solar. It has three different floors with an occupant family on each, and when the power goes down usually a random switch from either the big three controllers bottom-left or the three small ones on the top goes down, which I then have to re-enable.

Comment: I don't know what tools you have available there (is that Italian?), but the two options would be to turn off one circuit breaker ("switch") at a time and test every outlet and appliance to see what loses power, or to get a circuit tracer and work your way through all the outlets and lamps, generating a signal there and seeing which circuit breaker(s) that signal appears at.

Comment: Yikes!  I see most homes in Italy have meters limited to 3KW.  That is very tiny by US standards.  I suppose you have to manage your appliance use to avoid tripping the main breaker all the time.  Toaster plus microwave and you are in the dark.

Comment: Big three controllers in photo on the bottom-right (not bottom-left) are your electric meters, one for each floor, presumably.

Comment: I know right... light pops all the bloody TIME, and on top of that, our previous apartment had bad wiring and they all fried together in a near-pyrodisaster mess. Yeah, Italy sucks.

Comment: Yes, the three bottom controllers are the meters for the floors, although I don't know why one time they click and another time the upper ones do. Unfortunately I don't think I have a circuit tracer, also my owner would probably say otherwise seeing me going around and switching other people houses off at random. It was, after all, mostly out of curiosity, although it sure would help to know the difference between the two sets of controllers.

Comment: Dang!  with a 3kw limit, I'm surprised people don't use battery banks to charge up when they're asleep or at work, and suppliment load when they're home.

Comment: We actually would, if we had the money for it :/